# how to have first item selected by default in listview with radio buttons in android?

Tags: java, android, listview

I have a listview with radio buttons displaying some items in my android app. I want to have first option selected by default in this listview. Thanks in advance.

Comment: put some code here

Answer (score 0):

You should checked true property set when list view created array index is zero is find then you can get the first radio will be selected in list view.

Comment: i used the following code :-  
    final ArrayList<String> myList = (ArrayList<String>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("mylist"); 

        mylv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);

        final ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter= new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice,myList);
        
mylv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

Answer (score 0):

When you override `getView()`in your adapter, you could use the position in order to check the first item in your ListView.

```
RadioButton item;
if (null == view) {
    //add code for new view
}
else {
    item = (RadioButton) view;
    if (position == 0) {
        item.setChecked(true);
    }
    else {
        item.setChecked(false);
    }
}
```

This is what I was using as a resource:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html